# Unit testing Angular 6 location go back

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I need simple unit testing of location go back.

**main.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-information',
  templateUrl: './product-information.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-information.component.scss']
})
export class ProductInformationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private location: Location
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  close(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

Tried in **main.spec.ts**

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProductInformationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement;
    loc = jasmine.createSpyObj('Location', ['back']);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should clicked back', () => {
    el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.btn-cancel')).nativeElement.click();
    expect(loc.back).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

It didnt worked i got error

**Expected spy Location.back to have been called once. It was called 0 times.**

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to answer. I just faced this issue today and come up with below solution.

Use `SpyLocation` from `@angular/common/testing`

and code as follows

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SpyLocation } from '@angular/common/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { KnowMoreComponent } from './know-more.component';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

describe('KnowMoreComponent', () => {
  let component: KnowMoreComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<KnowMoreComponent>;
  let location: SpyLocation;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [KnowMoreComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: Location, useClass: SpyLocation }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(KnowMoreComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    location = TestBed.get(Location);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should go back to previous page on header button click', () => {
    spyOn(location, 'back');
    component.goBack();
    expect(location.back).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Hope this helps someone in future!

Answer (score 0):

We can create a location Stub.

Try like this:

```
describe('EditFaqsComponent', () => {
  let location;

  const locationStub = {
    back: jasmine.createSpy('back')
  }

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [..],
      declarations: [..],
      providers: [
        {provide: Location, useValue: locationStub},
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    ...
    location = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Location);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

 it('should go back', () => {
    component.close();
    expect(location.back).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });

});
```